# Having issues with a Makefile for a c++ project written in Xcode

Tags: c++, makefile

I wrote this c++ project in Xcode, and now I have to create a Makefile so that it compiles properly. Here is the Makefile:

```
CC = g++
CFLAGS =

PROG = TrainStation
MAIN = main.cpp
OBJS = ArrivalEvent.o DepartureEvent.o Event.o EventCoordinator.o InSwitchEvent.o ListItem.o OrderedList.o OutSwitchEvent.o PriorityQueue.o Train.o

# compiling rules

# WARNING: *must* have a tab before each definition
$(PROG): $(OBJS) main.o # The error was leaving out main.o from this line
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(OBJS) main.o -o $(PROG)

ArrivalEvent.o: ArrivalEvent.cpp ArrivalEvent.h EventCoordinator.h InSwitchEvent.h Event.h EventCoordinator.h Train.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c ArrivalEvent.cpp -o ArrivalEvent.o

DepartureEvent.o: DepartureEvent.cpp DepartureEvent.h OutSwitchEvent.h Event.h EventCoordinator.h Train.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c DepartureEvent.cpp -o DepartureEvent.o

Event.o: Event.cpp Event.h EventCoordinator.h ListItem.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c Event.cpp -o Event.o

EventCoordinator.o: EventCoordinator.cpp EventCoordinator.h OrderedList.h Event.h Train.h PriorityQueue.h ArrivalEvent.h InSwitchEvent.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c EventCoordinator.cpp -o EventCoordinator.o

InSwitchEvent.o: InSwitchEvent.cpp InSwitchEvent.h DepartureEvent.h Event.h EventCoordinator.h Train.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c InSwitchEvent.cpp -o InSwitchEvent.o

ListItem.o: ListItem.cpp ListItem.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c ListItem.cpp -o ListItem.o

OrderedList.o: OrderedList.cpp OrderedList.h ListItem.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c OrderedList.cpp -o OrderedList.o

OutSwitchEvent.o: OutSwitchEvent.cpp OutSwitchEvent.h Train.h InSwitchEvent.h Event.h EventCoordinator.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c OutSwitchEvent.cpp -o OutSwitchEvent.o

PriorityQueue.o: PriorityQueue.cpp PriorityQueue.h OrderedList.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c PriorityQueue.cpp -o PriorityQueue.o

Train.o: Train.cpp Train.h ListItem.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c Train.cpp -o Train.o

main.o: $(MAIN) Train.h OrderedList.h PriorityQueue.h EventCoordinator.h 
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $(MAIN) -o main.o

clean:
    rm -f $(PROG) $(OBJS)
```

I have written Makefiles before, but never one with so many files to coordinate, and it seems that it is skipping the rule for main.o [EDIT: I updated my Makefile but now receive this different error]

```
$ make
g++  -c ArrivalEvent.cpp -o ArrivalEvent.o
g++  -c DepartureEvent.cpp -o DepartureEvent.o
g++  -c Event.cpp -o Event.o
g++  -c EventCoordinator.cpp -o EventCoordinator.o
g++  -c InSwitchEvent.cpp -o InSwitchEvent.o
g++  -c ListItem.cpp -o ListItem.o
g++  -c OrderedList.cpp -o OrderedList.o
g++  -c OutSwitchEvent.cpp -o OutSwitchEvent.o
g++  -c PriorityQueue.cpp -o PriorityQueue.o
g++  -c Train.cpp -o Train.o
g++  main.o ArrivalEvent.o DepartureEvent.o Event.o EventCoordinator.o InSwitchEvent.o ListItem.o OrderedList.o OutSwitchEvent.o PriorityQueue.o Train.o -o TrainStation
i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-g++-4.2: main.o: No such file or directory
make: *** [TrainStation] Error 1
```

I know this is an error with g++, and that it probably has to do with me leaving out a file somewhere or not linking it, but I can't seem to figure out what is going wrong. Perhaps someone with fresh eyes may be able to spot the problem?

**EDIT: PROBLEM SOLVED**

My problem was that `$(OBJS)` doesn't contain `main.o`, so the rule for `$(PROG)` doesn't depend on `main.o` at all. Once I added `main.o` to the rule for `$(PROG)`, then the rule for `main.o` is executed correctly.

Comment: grep for where `_main` is defined and check if that is included above

Comment: `main.o` is not being linked, due to which it isn't compiled either, but that is secondary.

Comment: _main isn't defined by me in any code anywhere. I am pretty sure it's some internal compiler thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After `MAIN = main.cpp` you do never use this variable to compile and link the main.cpp file.

Change this:

```
$(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(OBJS) -o $(PROG)
```

to this:

```
$(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(OBJS) main.o -o $(PROG)
```

Comment: I did this, but now I get another error. After executing the rule for Train.o, it jumps to the first rule and then says that main.o doesn't exist.

It seems to completely ignore the rule for main.o

Comment: @MichaelThiessen, why don't you let XCode create the Makefile for you?

Comment: @MichaelThiessen, could you replace the `$(MAIN)` with `main.cpp` in the `main.o` target?

Comment: Yes, that doesn't change anything. I still have the same error. It doesn't create main.o so it can't find it when trying to link it.

Comment: @MichaelThiessen, try to run `g++ -c main.cpp -o main.o` in the terminal.

Comment: Manually compiled main.o, then ran the makefile, and it compiles and runs perfectly! Obviously the error is within the makefile somewhere.